# Is it possible to only pick one type of argument if you have two or three?-Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am parsing command line arguments, they are just a letter one and a number one ( this is just school homework). Right now I have

```
List<Letters> letters = new ArrayList<Letters>();
List<Numbers> numbers = new ArrayList<Numbers>();
 boolean letterFlag = false;
 boolean numberFlag = false;
for(String arg: args){
if ("-letter".equals(arg)) {
                letterFlag = true;
                numberFlag = false;
            } else if ("-number".equals(arg)) {
                numberFlag = true;
                letterFlag = false;
            } else if (letterFlag) {

                letters.add(Letter.valueOf(arg.toUpperCase()));
            } else if (numberFlag) {
                numbers.add(Number.valueOf(arg.toUpperCase()));
            }/*else if(letterFlag && !numberFlag)
            {
                letters.add(Letter.valueOf(arg));
                numbers.addAll(Number.values());
            }
            else if(numberFlag && !letterFlag)
            {
                numbers.add(Number.valueOf(arg));
                letters.addAll(Letters.values());

            }*/
                  else {
                System.out.printf("Invalid argument: %s%n", arg);
            }
         }
        TestClass.testMethod(letters, numbers)
```

With this code when I comment out what I have commented out I can give it a list of numbers and letters in either order but I also need to be able to do either just numbers or just letters and it work but I don't see what is wrong with my logic. Thank you in advance

Comment: @resueman that's correct sorry about that

Comment: You are using the wrong indexes. Your are first checking `"-number".equals(arg)` and then try to pars arg (which is "-number") as a number. You have to move your index +1.

Comment: @Philippe well it works if I do something like -number one two three -letter A B C but I doesnt work if I do -number one two three

Comment: What are `Letters.values()` and `Numbers.values()`?

Comment: @resueman When you ask what are they what exactly do you mean? They should be all of the values of the two enums.

Comment: please give us the input you give and the error you get. (or the specifics of what is wrong with the result of your program)

Comment: @ljgw If I input -number one two three -letter A B C it runs, printing me the toStrings of both. If I just do -number one two three it says its missing the other enum value

Comment: My mistake, I've missed these were all else/if

Comment: Please show us the code behind `TestClass.testMethod(letters, numbers)`: I suspect it cannot handle an empty List.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the situation (homework) I suspect that TestClass is a course-provided class.

Perhaps there is an option to submit only letters or only numbers with `TestClass.testMethod(letters)` and `TestClass.testMethod(numbers)`.

In that case you should probably only call that method with the single argument, it appears that it will fail when an empty List is provided.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I decided to add everything to both list before hand and if I give arguments, clear the list and add the arguments other wise use the list. But maybe you can help me "clean" my code a little? Is there a way to loop over the enum and add everything to the list? rather than add each item one line per item?

Comment: Ehm,... `for (Letter letter : Letter.values()) { letters.add(letter);}` or `List<Letter> letters = Arrays.asList(Letter.values());` .. however, cleaning your code might be more in place on codereview.stackexchange.com,... if phrased correctly. I mean, it's still homework...